# $f$ is injective iff $f \circ g_1 = f \circ g_2$ implies $g_1 = g_2$

Tags: analysis, functions

Let $f:A \rightarrow B$ be a map of sets. Prove that $f$ is injective if and only if given any set $C$ and any two set map $g_i:C \rightarrow A, i =1,2$, with compositions  $f \circ g_1 = f \circ g_2$, then $g_1 = g_2$.

So I have proved the forward direction, which was quite easy. For the other direction, I am unsure if my approach is correct:

$(\Leftarrow):$ suppose that  $f \circ g_1 = f \circ g_2$ implies $g_1 = g_2$ for any $g_1$ and $g_2$. And suppose that $f$ is not injective.

i.e. there exist $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$ such that  $f(g_1(x)) = f(g_2(x))$ and $g_1(x) \neq g_2(x)$

since $f(g_1(x)) = f(g_2(x))=f \circ g_1(x) = f \circ g_2(x)$, but our assumption $g_1=g_2$, and thus  $g_1(x) = g_2(x)$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Say what $C$ you are using and how you get $g_1, g_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming more than you need to. You are going for a contradiction, but the contrapositive works just fine.

Assume $f$ is not injective, so there exists $a_1\neq a_2$ such that $f(a_1)=f(a_2)$. Now, consider a set $C=\{*\}$ with one element. Can you construct $g_1,g_2:C\to A$ such that $f(g_1(*))=f(g_2(*))$?

Comment: Good point! Thanks